# error in installing weather-cli in python, windows 10

Tags: python, windows, pip, weather

[Please click on the image to see the error in detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnmVf.png)

```
Collecting tabletext>=0.1
  Using cached tabletext-0.1.tar.gz (6.1 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m45cftuh\\tabletext\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m45cftuh\\tabletext\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m45cftuh\tabletext\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m45cftuh\tabletext\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m45cftuh\tabletext\setup.py", line 10, in <module>
        + open("CHANGELOG.rst").read(),
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 1413: character maps to <undefined>
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: So– did you check the logs for full command output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the same as [this github issue](https://github.com/Thibauth/tabletext/issues/1) which has since been fixed.

Simply do

```
pip install git+git://github.com/Thibauth/tabletext
```

and then try installing `weather-cli` again

Comment: Thanks . It worked just fine.....